# Qt5 QNetworkAccessManager sends request twice

Tags: c++, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

Good day!

I am having a wierd problem: QNAM sends my **SECOND** request twice. I am not sure how to reproduce the problem (what are actual prerequisites), but I have the [code that will demonstrate it 100% of the time](http://pastebin.com/JH6uP0Yp). I can also provide [screenshot of HTTP sniffer catching those requests](http://i.pixs.ru/storage/9/0/5/dupepng_9599015_8255905.png). You can see that the request I send at code line **42** effectively gets duped, but the one before and one after (not shown) are sent fine (once)...

My problem is similar to the one shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803476/qnetworkaccessmanager-sends-get-two-time).
However...
Main differences between that question and mine are:

- I am using QNAM in an asynchronous manner with the help of Qt's Signals and slots
- I am sending post requests instead of get.

What could be the problem? Is there any way to make it work as it's supposed to?

Thanks in advance! If you need additional info just ask :)

Comment: Check out my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803476/qnetworkaccessmanager-sends-get-two-times/13882519#13882519. Does that help any?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You see, if by your answer you mean I need to change my code in a manner similar to yours, then you can look at the [link](http://pastebin.com/JH6uP0Yp): `http::steam_login` is same as `someClass::run` (it sends request and connects signal) and `http::login_reciever` is same as `someClass::on_request_complete` (handles the signal, login reciever handles it multiple times). **Or did you mean something else?**

Comment: Another detail: I've experienced this on both 32 and 64 bit qt, BUT: I use fiddler for debugging network communication and run all my requests through it with `QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(QNetworkProxy(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy,"localhost",8887));` and **when I dont add this line of code, request dupe does not occur... Is there something wrong with proxy support????**

Comment: What operating system are you testing on? I have had some weird proxy issues with qt5 on the mac - details posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707124/on-macosx-qnetworkaccessmanager-gets-into-an-infinite-loop-when-invalid-auth-cr/15707366#15707366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if the server doesn't return any content in the response. If you control the server, you can add a workaround to return some dummy content.

I just had this issue and after sending down one character in the response, I no longer see the request sent twice. This was with a BlackBerry 10 (QT) hitting an iOS device running Mongoose as the embedded server.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not control the server, and as far as I know it always returns something, even if input data was wrong... Thanks for your reply